# How can I call a WCF service from a SendAndReceiveReply Activity in WF (.Net 4.5)?

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow-foundation

I have a WCF service that is locally created in C# (with a [ServiceContract] and [DataContract]) and uses webHttpBinding for binding.

I would like to invoke "GET" and "POST" operations outlined in the contract from a WF workflow, but I just can't seem to get anything to work. Here are some of the things I've tried (from VisualStudio 2012):

1. Adding a service reference. I hear this is supposed to create the activities I want (after compiling), but I can only find my service by running it and finding it by address. I cannot "Discover" the service, even if I include the projects for the service in my solution that has the Workflow project. No activities are created as a result.
2. Importing a service contract. This seems to work a little better, in that I get activities, but I only get ReceiveAndSendReply activities. It doesn't seem to matter whether I make the contract as part of my Workflow project (and import it), or create a normal reference to the service's WCF project (and then import the contract through that reference).
3. Filling in the fields of the Send and ReceiveReplyForSend components of a SendAndReceiveReply activity directly (this was actually what I tried first). No matter what I try, I always run into a wall with the error, "Manual addressing is enabled on this factory, so all messages sent must be pre-addressed."

This seems like something that should be fundamental to WF and a lot easier, but I'm just not getting it. Am I missing something simple?